# How to deal with string-like values between xml tags in an xtext grammar

Tags: parsing, xml-parsing, xtext, xtend

I am attempting to create a strongly defined xml language, but have run into trouble on element values between element tags. I want them to be treated like a string except they are not wrapped in quotes. Here is a basic grammar I created to demonstrate the idea:

```
grammar org.xtext.example.myxml.MyXml hidden(WS)

generate myXml "http://www.xtext.org/example/myxml/MyXml"

import "http://www.eclipse.org/emf/2002/Ecore" as ecore

Element:
    {Element}
    '<Element' attributes+=ElementAttribute* ('/>' | '>'
        subElement+=SubElement*
    '</Element' '>')
;
SubElement:
    {SubElement}
    '<SubElement' attributes+=SubElementAttribute* ('/>' | '>' 
        value=ElementValue
    '</SubElement' '>')
;
ElementAttribute:
    NameAttribute | TypeAttribute
;
SubElementAttribute:
    NameAttribute
;

TypeAttribute:
    'type' '=' type=STRING
;
NameAttribute:
    'name' '=' name=STRING
;

ElementValue hidden():
    value=ID
;

terminal STRING:
            '"' ( '\\' . /* 'b'|'t'|'n'|'f'|'r'|'u'|'"'|"'"|'\\' */ | !('\\'|'"') )* '"' |
            "'" ( '\\' . /* 'b'|'t'|'n'|'f'|'r'|'u'|'"'|"'"|'\\' */ | !('\\'|"'") )* "'"
        ;
terminal WS: (' '|'\t'|'\r'|'\n')+;
terminal ID: '^'?('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_'|'0'..'9'|':'|'-'|'('|')')*;
```

Here is a test to demonstrate its usage:

```
@Test
    def void parseXML() {
        val result = parseHelper.parse('''
            <Element type="myType" name="myName">
                <SubElement>some string:like-stuff here </SubElement>
            </Element>
        ''')
        Assert.assertNotNull(result)
        val errors = result.eResource.errors
        for (error : errors) {
            println(error.message)
        }
    }
```

The error I get from this exact code is `mismatched input 'string:like-stuff' expecting '</SubElement'`
Obviously this will not work because `ID` does not allow for white space, adding white space to `ID` fixes the above error, but causes other issues parsing. So my question is how can I parse the element value into a string-like representation without causing ambiguity for the parser in other areas. The only way I have been able to get this to work in any form in my full language is by turning the `ElementValue` into a list of `ID's` separated by white space. (I could not get it to work on this minimal example however, not sure what is different)

Comment: is there a reason doing this with Xtext and not with the ecore xml schema support?

Comment: @ChristianDietrich I am not very familiar with that. My end need is that I need to be able to parse and serialize this xml file. Then from another grammar I have (not xml based), I will want to cross reference to certain elements in this model. Is that something I can achieve with what you mentioned? If so would you mind pointing me in the right direction?

Comment: if you have installed a emf sdk you will be able to turn a xml schema into an ecore and get serialization and deserialization for that http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.emf.doc%2Ftutorials%2Fxlibmod%2Fxlibmod.html. by implementing a iresourceserviceprovider  you will be able to refer from a xtext based file into the ecore based file

Comment: @ChristianDietrich Okay, I will give that a look. So is there not a solution to my original question? I have the grammar completed apart from that one issue, so it would be easy to finish if that can be solved

Answer (score 0):

I would not really recommend it because Xtext is usually not the best fit for XML parsing, but it would probably be possible by turning ElementValue into a [datatype rule](https://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/301_grammarlanguage.html#datatype-rules) that allows everything that doesn't create an ambiguity.

Something along the lines of:

```
ElementValue returns ecore::EString hidden(): (ID|WS|STRING|UNMATCHED)+ ;
```

and at the end of the grammar:

```
terminal UNMATCHED: .;
```

You will probably want to make SubElement.value optional to allow for an empty element.

```
value=ElementValue?
```